# No debugging symbols found in Visual Studio when built C program with Bazel(Windows)

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, bazel

I have simple C program. I want to build and debug C program using Bazel on Windows within Visual Studio Code . But getting error as: (No debugging symbols found in bazel-bin/examples/application/application). How can I get Symbols.
I have `cc_binary` :

```
cc_bin`enter code here`ary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = glob(["*.c"]),
  deps = [
    "//examples/sub_main",
  ],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

I'm using following command to build and debug.
bazel build --compilation_mode=dbg //examples/main --strip=never
gdb bazel-bin/examples/main/main
But I'm getting error as: (No debugging symbols found in bazel-bin/examples/application/application)
Even after using compilation_mode ad dbg why is it not generating any Symbols? How can I get symbols to debug? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [link](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/IrtTITtaSvs)

Answer :  You need to add "build --linkopt /debug" to your .bazelrc file.